# Modeling best practices

Tags: aframe

I worked some days on models that should be used with aframe, built with blender, exported to .obj. All went mostly very well, so the experience so far was very positive.

Until an object started to throw exceptions after some small changes at a model that worked well so far. The stacktrace is

```
aframe.js:sourcemap:27095 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
    at initMaterial (aframe.js:sourcemap:27095)
    at setProgram (aframe.js:sourcemap:27191)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (aframe.js:sourcemap:26139)
    at renderObjects (aframe.js:sourcemap:26961)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (aframe.js:sourcemap:26698)
    at THREE.VREffect.render (aframe.js:sourcemap:79772)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe.js:sourcemap:74829)
    at bound (aframe.js:sourcemap:78097)
56aframe.js:sourcemap:27732 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'needsUpdate' of undefined
    at markUniformsLightsNeedsUpdate (aframe.js:sourcemap:27732)
    at setProgram (aframe.js:sourcemap:27325)
    at WebGLRenderer.renderBufferDirect (aframe.js:sourcemap:26139)
    at renderObjects (aframe.js:sourcemap:26961)
    at WebGLRenderer.render (aframe.js:sourcemap:26698)
    at THREE.VREffect.render (aframe.js:sourcemap:79772)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe.js:sourcemap:74829)
    at bound (aframe.js:sourcemap:78097)
```

I found the problematic object, so I just rebuild it, no big deal this time.

But: When such a problem pops up later in the process, it might not be so easy to just rebuild. So my question is if there are any general tips to prevent such breakage. For example what to watch out for or what blender features to stay away from.

It's easy to rebuild the model now, but might be much harder later in the production process. I'd like to prevent this in the future.

Exporting from blender to gltf failed for me with pretty simple objects already.

Comment: I don't know what to make of that error; want to share a broken model? For glTF, if you're using the [newer exporter](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/), please file bugs or ask for help with it, because glTF is what we recommend generally.